# Overwrite when click submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, html-table

I have a problem with my Pixel Art Maker.

**Here is my HTML code:**

```
<body>

<h1> PIXEL ART MAKER </h1>



<form class='gridForm' >
    Grid Height: 
    <input type="number" id="gridHeight">
    Grid Width: 
    <input type="number" id="gridWidth">
    <input type="submit">   
</form>



<div class='colorPicker'>Pick a color 
<input type='color' name='colorCanvas'> </div>

<p class='designCanvas'>Design Canvas</p>
<table id='pixels'>


</table>


<script src="app.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
```

**And JS:**

```
function makeGrid() {

$(".gridForm").submit(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();

 x=$('#gridHeight').val(); // value of height
 y=$('#gridWidth').val();  // value of width


    for(i=0; x>i;x--){
        $('#pixels').append('<tr><td></td></tr>');
    }

    for(j=1; y>j ;y--){
        $('tr').append('<td></td>');
    }   

});

}

makeGrid();
```

Everything work as I want except 1 thing. When I choose height and width and click submit it creates the correct table form but when I choose other values and again click submit it just add new new table cells to old one. And I need new one to overwrite the old ones each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clear the table, please put this in the top of the function

```
$('#pixels').html("");
```

Comment: Thanks so much for help :) 
It was easy but at the same time I was stuck on this

Comment: glad to hear if,  It it works, please "accept" the answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have used $('#pixels').append() to dynamically insert html. So it will keep on appending to what you have before. If you want to override the previous html you have its better to clear before you start anything.

```
function makeGrid() {

  $(".gridForm").submit(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();

 x=$('#gridHeight').val(); // value of height
 y=$('#gridWidth').val();  // value of width
 $('#pixels').html("");
 $('tr').html("");

    for(i=0; x>i;x--){
        $('#pixels').append('<tr><td></td></tr>');
    }

    for(j=1; y>j ;y--){
        $('tr').append('<td></td>');
    }   

});

}

makeGrid();
```